# Convert binary string to unicode

Tags: python-3.x, encoding

I'm new at programming in python3 and am trying to figure out a way to convert a binary **string** to Unicode (utf-8). From my research, I found a way to first convert the binary string to text, then the text to Unicode.

Here's what I have so far:

```
plaintext = "0111011000110010001100"
#First convert binary to text
plaintextBinary = int(plaintext, 2)
byteNumber = plaintextBinary.bit_length() + 7 // 8
plaintextArray = plaintextBinary.to_bytes(byteNumber, "big")
plaintext = plaintextArray.decode()
#Then text to unicode
plaintext = [ord(c) for c in plaintext]
```

I also need the result to be as an array [x,y,z,...].
The code is not working, and I don't really understand what is going on either...

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you give an example of what your input looks like? The phrase "binary string" is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: Of course! I mean that the user is inputting a string of 1 and 0s: plaintext = str(input("Enter your message: ")).

Comment: Perhaps you could [edit] in a hard-coded example, with its expected output, so that the code formed a [mcve].

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Basically what I want is: if I have an inputted string of binary digits, is it possible to convert it to Unicode in the format [ x, y, z ]

Comment: Thanks for the help btw! I'm sorry if i don't understand everything you say :)

Comment: I was just suggesting that a concrete example would make it easier for other people to test versions of the code. So, instead of `plaintext = str(input("Enter your message: "))` something like `plaintext = "0111011000110010001100"` or whatever. Similarly, show the specific output for that example; when you said "to Unicode", I assumed you meant an actual string ready to display, not an array of codepoint numbers; so rather than `[ x, y, z ]`, you can explicitly show `[52. 1235, 2134]` or whatever.

Comment: Corrected my question

Comment: That string of binary was literally me pressing the 0 and 1 buttons on my keyboard at random, it's not likely to be a valid input to your function; I don't think it's even a multiple of eight bits long. That's why I was suggesting that you come with an example of the actual strings you're expecting, and the actual results you want out the other end.

Comment: **1.** Make reckoning of operator precedence: `a + b // c`  differs from `(a + b) // c`; **2.** Not all byte sequences are valid `utf-8` ones!

Answer (score 0):

What **kevin samuel** had come up by himself, except missing brackets in the calculation of `byteNumer` and a binary string which can't be converted to UTF-8, was as good as what he was looking for.
The code below is working in Python 3.6 and I tried to make it self explanatory:

```
plaintext = "100111010101010101010101010101"
print(type(plaintext)) # gives: <class 'str'>

# make an integer value out of the Unicode string with '0's and '1's: 
plaintextAsInteger = int(plaintext, 2)
byteNumber = ( plaintextAsInteger.bit_length() + 7 ) // 8
print(plaintextAsInteger, byteNumber) # gives: 659903829 4

plaintextBytesString = plaintextAsInteger.to_bytes(byteNumber, "big")
print(type(plaintextBytesString), plaintextBytesString) # gives <class 'bytes'> b"'UUU"

# Then text to unicode
unicodeTextString = plaintextBytesString.decode() # as UTF-8 standard
plaintext = unicodeTextString
print(type(plaintext), len(plaintext), plaintext) # gives: <class 'str'> 4 'UUU

# Then text to a list ( a one dimensional array )
plaintextArray = [ord(c) for c in plaintext]
print(plaintextArray) # gives: [39, 85, 85, 85]

# let's show that the code gives values > 255 (Unicode code)
plaintextArray = [ord(c) for c in "æœ©®"] 
print(plaintextArray) # gives: [230, 339, 169, 174]
```

See https://timothybramlett.com/Strings_Bytes_and_Unicode_in_Python_2_and_3.html for some basics on bytes vs. Unicode.